# Non capisco "solo più"

Tags: regional, adverbs, phrases

Non capisco l'uso di "solo" e "più".

Esempio:

Se compro pagnotte "ne voglio solo più due", capisco "più due", due più alle pagnotte che ho. "Solo" perché "solo due", solo poche.

Poi, ieri mi hanno detto "Sei rimasta solo più tu". Io sono "solo"? Sola? Sono sola io più io? Mi hanno spiegato che vuol dire "Sei rimasta solamente tu" e io capisco di meno. Questa costruzione è difficile, qualcuno me la può spiegare?

Comment: A quanto ne so questa costruzione è regionale, in uso solo in alcune regioni del Nord. Quindi sei in buona compagnia, penso che la maggior parte degli italiani madre lingua non la capirebbe (o perlomeno la capirebbe dal contesto, ma la troverebbe molto insolita).

Comment: La usa mia cugina, nata e cresciuta in Liguria. Credo sia ligure/piemontese, probabilmente su influsso del francese.

Comment: Secondo questo [articolo](https://www.academia.edu/20144229/Citizen_sociolinguistics_e_ironia_online_il_caso_del_pensionato_torinese_su_Facebook), che usa l'abbreviazione PRI per indicare la "varietà di italiano (popolare) regionale piemontese", l'uso di "solo più" col significato di "ancora soltanto" è rappresentativo di questo PRI.

Comment: Si afferma: «Benché “emerg[a] sporadicamente anche nelle produzioni linguistiche di parlanti non piemontesi” (Cerruti 2013: 140, cfr. anche Cerruti&Pandolfi 2012) e sia osservabile anche in altre varietà regionali, non necessariamente a causa del contatto col PRI, *solo più* è comunque un tratto tipico di PRI e quindi riconosciuto come tale anche dai CS». CS sta per "citizen sociolinguists", cioè, parlanti comuni.

Comment: Io sono di Roma: avrò sentito questa costruzione un paio di volte in vita mia, da settentrionali, e io stesso non sono sicuro di come interpretarla. Suppongo che significhi “solo”? Forse nel caso delle pagnotte “solo altre due”?

Comment: Io sono di Venezia e non credo di averla mai sentita. Sicuramente regionale, anch'io sono insicuro di come interpretarla.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anch'io la conosco solo per averla sentita da amici piemontesi, però (sulla base delle loro spiegazioni) posso provare a dirti qualcosa. Tutto questo purtroppo non ha altri riferimenti che non "mi hanno detto" (che, me ne rendo conto, non è l'ideale per questo sito).

Per capire questa costruzione, pensa prima a

> Non ci sono **più** pagnotte / Non ce ne sono **più**.

che significa *prima c'erano delle pagnotte, ora però sono finite*.

Analogamente, uno potrebbe pensare di dire

> Ci sono solo **più** due pagnotte / Ce ne sono solo **più** due.

che significa *prima c'erano tre o più pagnotte, ora però ne sono rimaste solo due.*

L'uso dell'avverbio *più* è analogo nelle due costruzioni, e serve a sottolineare un contrasto tra prima e dopo; l'accezione è l'1c della voce del [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/piu):

> In frasi negative serve a indicare la cessazione definitiva di qualche cosa a cominciare da un certo limite (equivalendo a «di qui in avanti», «d’ora in poi»): Quel giorno più non vi leggemmo avante (Dante); ti prometto che non lo farò più; non voglio più sentirne parlare (e con più forza, mai più); non poterne più, essere al limite della sopportazione.

In frasi negative è italiano completamente standard; come dicono i commenti, in frasi affermative è un uso regionale che suona strano alla maggior parte dei parlanti. È un'espressione che (secondo me) ti conviene non imparare se stai studiando l'italiano.

È una costruzione che si usa comunemente in [francese](https://context.reverso.net/traduzione/francese-italiano/il+n%27y+a+plus+que), come notato da @egreg nei commenti. In italiano, per costruire una frase con lo stesso significato si usa solitamente un verbo come *restare*, *rimanere*, come ho fatto io sopra e come puoi vedere negli esempi di Reverso nel mio link.

Comment: Infatti, quest'altra [voce del Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/solo) riporta l'uso regionale di "solo più" col significato di "ancora soltanto", con questo esempio: "ci mancano solo più pochi giorni". Non sono per niente sicura, però, che questo sia l'unico uso regionale di "solo più".

Comment: Anche il [GDLI](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI19/00000366.jpg) registra l'uso regionale di "solo più" col significato di "ancora soltanto" e dà questi esempi: "gli restano solo più trenta giorni" (Migliorini); "solo più gli illusi, gli imbecilli e gli austriaci la combattono" (Gobetti).

Comment: Contrasto tra prima e dopo è un cambiamento di situazione sì? Ho capito grazie.

Answer (score 2):

Micina96, hai scoperchiato un vaso pieno di discussioni! Non immaginavo che fosse un argomento tanto dibattuto.

Pare che l'espressione "solo più" sia ritenuta, da molti, "puramente piemontese", sbagliata e, per giunta, pare che i poveri piemontesi non lo sappiano.

Nell'Enciclopedia dell'Italiano di Treccani (http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/italiano-di-torino_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/) c'è una spiegazione molto dettagliata su storpiature della lingua operate a Torino, tra le quali si trova anche questo "solo più". L'articolo è certamente completo, ma telegrafico e forse esagera un poco in certi casi dove si bollano come assolutamente locali costrutti ben legittimi in Italiano.

L'Accademia, in questo documento (https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/solo-o-soltanto-pi%C3%B9-%C3%A8-unespressione-solo-piemontese/271) inizia dicendo che è una "questione molto dibattuta [anche in passato sul nostro forum]", poi prosegue come al solito con molti cenni storici, citazioni di dizionari e pareri di altri eminenti studiosi, per finire senza chiare conclusioni.

Non soddisfatto di Treccani e Accademia ho fatto una semplice ricerca (facile, basta cercare "solo più" con Google), e ho trovato un mare di pagine. Tra quelle, https://chasingthequeen.wordpress.com/2014/01/26/il-solo-piu-spiegato-ai-non-piemontesi/ cerca di spiegare a "un non piemontese" le ragioni e il funzionamento del costrutto, ed è corredata di molte testimonianze di utenti che hanno commentato la pagina.

Mettendo insieme il tutto, direi che:

L'uso di "solo più" ha una sua "solidità", perché concisamente e chiaramente, usando parole semplici e normali, esprime un'idea difficilmente traducibile in italiano standard senza cambiare la frase di partenza. Questo può essere il motivo per cui chi dice "solo più" non avverte la "stranezza" del costrutto, rafforzato in ciò dal fatto che "solo più" è stato usato molte volte da scrittori e altre persone illustri, certamente non tacciabili d'ignoranza, ed è normalmente usato anche su quotidiani e altra carta stampata.

Nel sito citato prima, quello con molte testimonianze, si può capire che il "solo più" venga a volte percepito come normale anche fuori dal Piemonte: per esempio in Liguria, in Toscana, a Roma, nelle Puglie. Con le solite contraddizioni: alcuni utenti di Roma dicevano "mai sentito", altri asserivano "sì sì, si dice anche qui". Mistero.

Riguardo all'origine di "solo più", alcuni sostengono che è una costruzione presa dal Francese, che effettivamente ha influenzato il Piemontese; però a me non pare - la costruzione francese non ha lo stesso significato e, a ben guardare, il Piemontese si discosta dal Francese più di quanto sembri a prima vista. Sicuramente "solo più" è la traduzione diretta del piemontese "mac pì", dove "pì" significa esattamente "più", però "mac" non corrisponde esattamente a "solo".

Quando si sente "solo più" in Italiano, è difficile capire il ruolo delle due parole, visto che è un costrutto non contemplato ufficialmente... credo che @Federico Poloni, nella sua risposta in questa pagina, abbia fatto un buon lavoro.

Per tornare alle tue frasi:

> "ne voglio solo più due" (pagnotte)
>   "sei rimasta solo più tu"

Il "solo più" significa, sempre, un cambiamento di situazione; cioè: il "più" non si riferisce a "due", ma a "solo"; in definitiva: "prima ne volevo di più, ora solo due".

Infatti nella seconda frase non è "tu più tu", è "solo più" tu, cioè prima c'erano più persone, ma ora sei rimasta sola. La frase è ridondante perché "rimasta" e "solo più" dicono la stessa cosa, quindi "sei rimasta solo tu", "tu sei rimasta [la] sola" e "sei solo più tu" sono alternative non ridondanti.

Comment: Grazie linuxfan, la tua risposta è più complicata di la mia domanda, ma un cambiamento di situazione" spiega bene.

Answer (score 1):

Io sono piemontese e la risposta di Federico Poloni coglie appieno il significato del "solo piu". Io ho scoperto solo in età adulta che non fosse italiano corretto e che i non-piemontesi storgono il naso quando sentono "solo più". Continuo ad usarlo ma solo quando sono in presenza di piemontesi :)

Personalmente non capisco come il resto dell'Italia riesca a fare a meno di un'espressione così utile :D Comunque, sì, la derivazione non è francese ma dal piemontese "mac pì", che nella zona dove sono cresciuto io ha perso la "c" e si pronuncia "mapi" (accento tonico sulla "a"). Per esempio, "ci sono solo più due pagnotte" si direbbe "A-j son mapi doi miche d'pan".

Per tutti coloro che intendono imparare l'italiano, sconsiglierei di usarlo.

Answer (score 0):

A volte certe domande servono a farci riflettere su aspetti che, da parlanti "incoscienti", non avevamo considerato prima. Questa rientra nel novero e vale più di un upvote a mio avviso!

Da torinese torinese ho sempre pensato che "solo più" fosse italiano standard e ora mi ravvedo con piacere. La spiegazione di @federico poloni (tranne il confronto con il francese) e le osservazioni di linux mi sembrano molto plausibili.

Non è mia intenzione classificare questa costruzione come "dialettale" o "regionale", (cosa appurata visto che i non piemontesi non la capiscono), bensì cercare di capire come sia sorta.

Con il francese non ha nulla a che fare poiché "seulement plus" non si usa e non si trova.

Quello che succede in questo caso è un "blending". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conceptual_blending#Notes

Il "più" non è usato in funzione di quantificatore, ma in una funzione temporale che deriva da contesti di negazione: "non ho più tempo".

Ergo quello che accade è una estensione di "più" nel senso di "ormai" da asserzioni negative a asserzioni affermative.

Questo vale per "sei rimasta solo più tu".

Il discorso è un po' diverso per "ne voglio solo più due" riferito a pagnotte. In queso caso userei l'espressione solo per fermare il panettiere se stessi constatando che ha intenzione di riempirmi il sacchetto di pagnotte. Userei però l'imperfetto "ne volevo solo più". In questa accezione, a mio avviso, "più" preserva in gran parte la sua funzione di quantificatore.

Comment: Bentornato Nico. Io mi chiedo perché il "solo più" sia così difficile da accettare come italiano, benché usato da milioni di persone e presente in libri e stampa, e da tanto tempo, mentre "cachinnare", per esempio, per quanto ne so io è stato usato da due persone (ma facciamo pure 100) ma avrebbe pieno titolo di parola italiana.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: L'espressione "solo più" appare in molti dizionari italiani. Che io sappia, nessuno ha detto che non sia italiana: soltanto che è di uso regionale. E ti posso assicurare che se un termine è usato soltanto da due persone non si trova su nessun dizionario. I dizionari non si fanno in questo modo, ma su questo ne abbiamo già parlato.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Grazie! Piacere di rileggerti! Il discorso per me è questo: se qualcuno che proviene da un'altra regione dice di non capire l'espressione, credo a quello che dice anche se non avrei mai immaginato che potesse essere così. Questo a maggior ragione che si tratta di una costruzione grammaticale produttiva e non di un lessema magari raro. Quindi mi sono rassegnato pensando "ci mancava solo più questa" (sic;-)

Comment: @Charo Se fosse solo di uso regionale, non ci sarebbero diversi utenti che sostengono di non saperla interpretare (vedi tutto il filone). Non parliamo di lessico qui, ma di una costruzione grammaticale.