# Significato e uso di "dare la larga"

Tags: word-usage, meaning, regional

Nel racconto *Nichel* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> I ladri di tacchini erano loro due, lui e il cane. Alla domenica lui portava il cane in paese, girava per le cascine e gli faceva vedere quali erano i tacchini piú belli e meno custoditi; gli spiegava caso per caso la strategia migliore; poi tornavano alla miniera, e lui di notte gli **dava la larga**, e il cane arrivava invisibile, strisciando lungo i muri come un vero lupo, saltava il recinto del pollaio oppure scavava un passaggio sotto, accoppava in silenzio il tacchino e lo riportava al suo complice.

Ho cercato alla voce "largo" di parecchi dizionari, ma non sono riuscita a trovare l'espressione "dare la larga". Cosa significa? Magari lasciare libero qualcuno (il cane in questo caso)? Si tratta di una locuzione poco comune? Se invece non è un'espressione insolita, si può anche usare per riferirsi a persone?

**Aggiornamento:**

Ho cercato nei romanzi di Beppe Fenoglio e ho trovato altri esempi di questa espressione nella *Malora*, in cui ho visto che è utilizzata anche per una persona (anche qui l'uso del grassetto è mio):

> Posammo carro e bestia a uno stallaggio dove Tobia era conosciuto e mangiammo su uno scalino, senza parlare come i frati; io mandavo giú la roba senza sentirci il gusto, forza che volevo correre a vedere Emilio nel suo nuovo stato, Tobia capí e mi **diede la larga**, a ritrovarci lí per quattr’ore.

> La famiglia **diede la larga** al cane che aveva un’affezione speciale per il padrone vecchio e i figli gli tennero dietro per esserci al caso che trovasse, ma il cane che stava legato tutto l’anno se li portò dietro fin passato Le Grazie solo per trovare una sua cagna.

Può essere utile sapere che questo Tobia è il padrone di Agostino, l'io narrante, cioè, Agostino lavora per lui come contadino nella cascina del Pavaglione.

Anche nel testo di questo [spettacolo teatrale di Valerio Elampe e Alberto Canottiere](https://www.ateatro.info/copioni/quando-vanni-lo-chiamavano-bill/), promotori del [Laboratorio universitario teatrale di Alba](http://www.stpauls.it/ga06/0616ga/0616ga07.htm), si legge (grassetto mio):

> PADRE. Il cane ha bisogno di un padrone. Il padrone lo lega stretto, e gli **dà la larga** che morda solo chi porta occasione.

Quindi, si tratta di un'espressione di uso regionale?

Comment: Dare la larga al cane significa lasciarlo libero. E' un modo di dire più che altro da contadini (altri possessori di cani di solito non li lasciano liberi). Potrebbe essere usato solo dai piemontesi, ma non sono sicuro.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Di sicuro io non l'ho mai sentito prima d'ora.

Comment: @DenisNardin: il concetto è simile a "prendere il largo" e "stare alla larga"; in questo caso è il padrone che concede (da') "la larga". Leggendo autori piemontesi non è difficile incontrare questa locuzione (nel contesto adatto). Non mi pare di averlo letto da autori non piemontesi ma, se mi fosse capitato, probabilmente non ci avrei fatto caso.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Sono più che contento di crederti, ma dovresti scriverlo come risposta e non come commento.

Comment: @DenisNardin: non ho fonti. Se a Charo va bene lo stesso, lo dica lei.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: Per me va bene se scrivi tutto questo in una risposta.

Comment: Scusate, ma se @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica molto onestamente dice per primo di non avere fonti, perché caldeggiate che lo scriva? È interessante come commento, e lo ringrazio, ma come risposta, fino a prova contraria, è la testimonianza di una singola persona.

Answer (score 2):

Dare la larga (al cane) significa lasciarlo libero, concedergli la libertà. È un modo di dire più che altro da contadini, che tengono i cani legati nell'aia per fare la guardia e tenere "alla larga" gli animali selvatici (volpi e cinghiali soprattutto). Vita grama, quella del cane di cascina; ma, per rispetto e amore, ogni tanto il padrone gli concede qualche ora di libertà liberandolo dalla catena. Di solito il cane ritorna e, tanti anni fa, tornava di sicuro (per non morire di fame, oltre che per affetto).

L'espressione può essere usata in modo figurato, anche se non è esattamente gentile, in ogni caso in cui si abbia il potere di concedere la libertà ad animali o persone.

--- AGGIUNTA DOPO I COMMENTI ---

[Cercando su Google](https://www.google.it/search?tbm=bks&hl=it&q=%22d%C3%A0%20la%20larga%22) (come ha fatto Charo) escono tre risultati:

- un [testo sul teatro milanese](https://books.google.it/books?id=kYg2AAAAIAAJ&q=%22d%C3%A0%20la%20larga%22&dq=%22d%C3%A0%20la%20larga%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFppLQ_NDqAhW1xMQBHWb7DxkQ6AEwAnoECAAQAg), un po' fuori contesto, che dice che significa "lasciare libertà di fare, di spendere". Piemontese e milanese hanno qualche punto di contatto.
- Un [Vocabolario Piemontese-Italiano](https://books.google.it/books?id=ucxcPE7BcFwC&pg=PA347&dq=%22d%C3%A0%20la%20larga%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFppLQ_NDqAhW1xMQBHWb7DxkQ6AEwAHoECAIQAg) del 1830 che recita "scarcerare, sprigionare, far uscire di prigione, mettere in libertà"
- Un [dizionario multilingue](https://books.google.it/books?id=Qk-7S77TNU4C&pg=PA344&dq=%22d%C3%A0%20la%20larga%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFppLQ_NDqAhW1xMQBHWb7DxkQ6AEwAXoECAEQAg) che recita "scarcerare, sprigionare, far uscire di prigione, mettere in libertà" (guarda caso le stesse identiche parole, ma questo libro è precedente di 15 anni).

Però, il secondo ha un'altra accezione (più completo?) "dè la larga, o larghè le bestie", voce contadina, che significa condurre al pascolo le vacche i buoi eccetera (ma i cani non si fanno pascolare).

In entrambi i casi si tratta di pubblicazioni di 200 fa; occorre considerare che il Piemontese ormai è parlato molto più in campagna che in città.

Si potrebbe dedurre che 1) l'espressione ormai sia specialmente contadina; 2) usarla nel contesto sbagliato risulti facilmente offensivo, o scherzoso se va bene; in ogni caso un po' di cameratismo sarebbe consigliabile per usarla riferita a persone: cioè, andare in Piemonte e chiedere a un ex detenuto se "gli hanno dato la larga" è poco prudente.

Un ultimo pensiero, per inquadrare bene le cose, è che la locuzione "dare la larga" è la traduzione letterale di un modo di dire piemontese, analogamente al famoso e dibattuto ["solo più"](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/12807/non-capisco-solo-pi%C3%B9), ma mentre Ngram viewer per quest'ultima locuzione trova alcuni risultati, per "dare la larga" o simili non ne trova.

**Per riassumere e rispondere a tutti i quesiti posti dalla richiedente:**

> "dare la larga". Cosa significa? Magari lasciare libero qualcuno (il cane in questo caso)?

Sì.

> Si tratta di una locuzione poco comune?

A livello di italiano standard è senz'altro poco comune. Restringendo il campo al contesto adatto, cioé la campagna piemontese, è comune per indicare il gesto di liberare un animale o (un po' meno) una persona.

> Se invece non è un'espressione insolita, si può anche usare per riferirsi a persone?

Come detto sopra, il fatto che l'espressione possa essere "insolita" dipende dal contesto. Diciamo che assumendo che non sia insolita, sicuramente non è solitamente rivolta alle persone.

> Quindi, si tratta di un'espressione di uso regionale?

Si può dire di sì, o anche dire che è un'espressione di derivazione dialettale.

Comment: C'è anche un riferimento all'espressione "dare la larga" nel [libro di Villata](https://books.google.es/books?id=1sNUDwAAQBAJ&pg=PR97&lpg=PR97source=bl&ots=f9liAUv8iZ&sig=ACfU3U1SRGh7Y89b5wvhqaj9ZQ9pAt92uQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiqm5jFqY7qAhWKHhQKHQQuAB0Q6AEwBnoECAgQAQ#q=%22diede%20la%20larga%22&f=false): peccato che non si possano leggere le altre pagine.